# Action bar with written clickable?

Tags: android, button, android-actionbar

I would like to have an ActionBar in Android similar to evernote where in the top right there is a sign that if touched triggers an action. How do I put this in writing clickable? And as I move to the right?

Answer (score 0):

You need to override OnOptionsItemSelected() method in your activity. You can also check the for  [offical doc](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/actionbar.html) for full tutorial

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
// Handle item selection
switch (item.getItemId()) {
case R.id.menuItem1:
action1();
case R.id.menuItem2:
action2();       
default:
    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}
```

Good luck